# How to wrap text in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I have a JTextArea in Java.  When I place a large amount of text in it, the text area provides horizontal scrolling.

How can I make my text area wrap instead?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use the [`JTextArea#setLineWrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap(boolean)) method. This is also illustrated in the [Swing `JTextArea` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: That's a first. Most times I am too slow due to the creation of the links to the Javadoc which take some time, even if you know the API from the top of your head

Comment: You may also want to use [JTextArea#setWrapStyleWord](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord(boolean)) if don't want it to break words.

Answer (score 31):

Look at the API for the methods available to JTextArea, in particular `setWrapStyleWord` and `setLineWrap`.

Comment: tq very much btw eventhough robin answer first :D

Answer (score 18):

Try This :

```
jTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

In a Swing GUI Designer Like Netbeans IDE,

you could just 'check' the lineWrap in jTextArea property window.

if property window is hidden:

```
Goto WINDOW -> IDE TOOLS -> Properties
```

or press

```
CTRL + SHIFT + 7
```

In Swing GUI

add the line

```
jTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use this to wrap text with multiple words.

```
JTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the IntelliJ GUI Designer, you can just check the "lineWrap" box to get the wrapping functionality:
[image]